# Adding agent to inotes

Tags: lotus-notes

I have an agent which strips attachments from an email but preserves the email itself. I'd like to provide that same functionality to iNotes users.  Is there a way to add any additional functionality to the iNotes interface?

I know I could provide a mail-in db which would take email forwarded to it and strip off the attachments.  But it would be nice to just allow someone to do it right from the iNotes i/f like they do it now from Notes.

thanks
clem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the iNotes customization examples [here](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Lotus_iNotes_Customization_example__iNote). The very last line of the customized Forms85_x.nsf code adds an agent. See also this [technote](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_8.5.3/com.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc/H_CUSTOMIZING_THE_LOOK_OF_LOTUS_INOTES_STEPS.html) and this [presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/IBMSBT/learn-everything-about-ibm-inotes-customization).

Comment: Thanks Rich... Just what I needed!